# I can't change my button's size, and I want them to be stacked horizontally - not vertically

Tags: html, css, button

At the moment I have no control of my buttons, I want my buttons to be stacked horizontally with 30% width of #user-buttons. I read on the forum that the solution is to put Display: inside-block. But it didn't work. Any suggestion on how I should continue?

```css
#user-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.button {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-buttons" class="controls">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Hi">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Bye">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Maybe">
</div>
```

Comment: Display block works fine for me [example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/xwWyEz?editors=110)

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear enough, but i want every button to be 30% width, so it fills the user-button area

Comment: Your provided code looks correct. check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r28phxhu/ Could there be something else effecting your input's?

Comment: @JoJo You dont want any space on the sides? in other words the buttons fill up the parent so the red dosent show at all?

Comment: looks good like Shan Robertson did it, But i cant find whats effecting it. I guess my whole code project is to big to post it here.

Comment: heres the fiddle, look how buggy it seems where the buttons are. http://jsfiddle.net/x4mpu8v1/

Comment: @JoJo Seems like your button has a fixed width while the contains has a fluid one in percentages, you need to make the buttons in percentages or the container larger so the `200px` buttons fit in it something like this [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/x4mpu8v1/1/)

Comment: Hvala ti puno, its working now

Comment: @JoJo Nema nacemu :D, lemme post the answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container buttons need to be of a fluid width `width:100%` so it dosent overflow the containers width.

Code:

```
div.controls input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the fixed [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4mpu8v1/1/).

Comment: please add full code to answer so others may use in the future.

Comment: The solution is the opposite as OP ask? Sorry, but I laugh with the question *"I want them to be stacked horizontally - not vertically"* and his code working fine xDD

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Took a while in the comments to notice what was wrong, only way this makes sense if he reformates the question i guess.